# Reading asset image dimensions without loading into memory

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to find out the dimensions (width and height) of an asset file but without loading it into memory, or with as little memory usage as possible.

I'm currently doing:

`Image _mainMenuTable = Image.asset("images/main_menu_table.png");`

but won't that make a widget into memory and also load the image onto it ? Even if I don't display it anywhere.

I've also tried creating an `AssetImage`, which I'm already doing to set as the background image of a `Container`, but I can't retrieve the dimensions of the image from it.

Any ideas if there's a better way that `Image.asset`? This way, I am indeed getting my width and height dynamically, but it loads it into memory twice, no? Once as an `Image` and once as an `AssetImage`

**Disclaimer**: it's my second week into Flutter, so please be gentle in case the answer is obvious.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You just need to use the File class from the dart:io package.
Example -

```
import 'dart:io';

void main(){
  var file = File('file_path');
  file.length().then((len) => print(len)); //prints bytes
}
```

Comment: Hmm ... I require the width and height of the image, not it's zise. Though this could come in handy at some point.

Comment: To get the height and width we can use the decodeImageFromList() method, but it requires a List of bytes as it's argument, for which we will have to read the image. There must be some other way though. If we can somehow access the metadata of the image then it might help.

Comment: Yeah, exactly. It would do wonders for memory management. Still waiting for someone to answer though, might be something out there...